# (foo; echo $?) echoing empty string for functions that return >0 w/ set -e

Tags: bash, shell, shunit2

I'm trying to unit test some bash scripts. One of my functions returns 1 as a false value, which I can use in if tests like

```
foo() {
  return 0
}

if foo; then
  echo "Passed"
fi
```

This is really handy for writing clean code.

However when trying to unit test this code using [shunit2](http://shunit2.googlecode.com/), the `assertFalse` assertion needs a string value to test.

I've got around this by writing tests like this:

```
test_foo() {
  local result="$(foo; echo $?)"
  assertFalse "$result"
}
```

but this fails when `foo` returns `1`. The `echo $?` seems to be echoing an empty string, rather than the actual return code.

Any idea what's going on?

### edit

This only seems to occur when `set -e` is set. No idea why though.

Comment: I can't reproduce this using the code you provide in your question. Can you provide a tested reproducer?

Comment: ...for instance, the following works fine: `foo() { return 1; }; test_foo() { local result=$(foo; echo $?); echo "Result is $result"; }; test_foo`

Comment: Why don't you: `test_foo() { foo; assertFalse "$?"; }` ?

Comment: Found what was causing it: I had `set -e` on the top of my script I was testing. So what's going on there?

Comment: [Some people dislike `set -e`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105). Reason is simple: with `set -e`, the subshell `(foo; echo $?)` is aborted early if `foo` fails, and so the `echo` is never executed.

Comment: BANG @gniourf_gniourf has it! Submit that as the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: You say "One of my functions returns 1 as a false value", but your `foo()` function returns 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `set -e`, the subshell

```
(foo; echo $?)
```

exits if `foo` fails—and in this case exits immediately after `foo` returns— so `echo $?` is never executed.

As a side note, [some people dislike `set -e`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) (and there are good reasons for that, that you'll discover by reading the link).

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your test function should look like:

```
test_foo() {
  local result="$(foo; echo $?)"
  assertFalse "[ $result == 0 ]"
}
```

AssertFalse Usage:

```
assertFalse [message] condition
```

You can find usage [Here](http://shunit2.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/source/2.1/doc/shunit2.html#asserts)

Comment: In the doc you link: _The condition can be as simple as a shell false value (the value `1` -- equivalent to `${SHUNIT_FALSE}`)._ So that's clearly not an issue.

Comment: I disagree, OP assumes the $result is empty when it's probably just failing assertFalse, remeber for shell `1` = `false`

Comment: I missed his edit  about -e  `:D` getting late here, time to go to bed. good night!

Answer (score -5):

Try this code:

```
if [ foo == 0 ]
then
   echo "passed"
else
   echo "error"
fi
```

Comment: Sorry dude but that's not correct. `[` is a function that accepts parameters and returns the correct error or success code (`>0` or `0` respectively). If a function already returns a code then you can simply execute it directly in your `if`.

Comment: Also, `==` is invalid inside of POSIX test (`[ ]`); POSIX specifies `=` as the comparison operator; `==` is an extension provided by some shells, but the standard doesn't mandate its existence, so using it is a needless loss of compatibility.

Comment: what is the type of your parameters? -- int, str?

Comment: In the case of `if foo; then`, `foo` is a command (in the case of this question, a function). What the `if` branches on is that command's exit status. That exit status is necessarily numeric.

Comment: ...so, `[ ]` is not part of the `if` syntax, but is just a built-in command (with behavior similar to that of any other command -- no special parser extensions) that `if` can run and check the exit status of.

Comment: `[` is a (built-in) *command*, not a function (though it's used in much the same way).

Comment: `[ foo == 0 ]` (even on shells which support `==` -- which, as described above, is not guaranteed by POSIX) always returns false, as it runs a string comparison between the strings `"foo"` and `"0"`, which aren't identical. It does **not** run the function named `foo` and compare its exit status to 0, which is what the user is trying to accomplish. As such, even as edited, this answer is entirely wrong.